# SSL certs for hosted VMs on a single domain

Tags: tls, cloud-computing

We have 5 virtual machines on the Google Cloud platform to serve our multi-vendor web store. One domain name and 5 VMs: one for Magento, one for Akeneo, one for MySQL, one for MongoDB and the fifth for WordPress.

How many SSL certificates will we need to install to ensure full security? Is it one per VM, or one for the domain?

Answer (score 0):

At least one per IP if you want to secure all channels.

Some SSL providers offer certificates for IPs.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name

But make sure to enforce SSL.